# search for specific process name in htop

Tags: htop

I would like to quickly find if my process is running by searching its name in htop. I could only find the PID or list all process one by one which not convenient.

Comment: For the impatient: ```\```

Answer (score 107):

## Search

Press `F3` or `/` and start typing in the process name to *search*: highlights closest matching result amongst all entries.

## Filter

If you only want results matching your query to be shown, you could *filter* instead: press `F4` or `\` to *filter*

[From the htop manual:](https://linux.die.net/man/1/htop)

> `F3`, `/`: Incrementally search the command lines of all the displayed processes. The currently selected (highlighted) command will update as you type. While in search mode, pressing F3 will cycle through matching occurrences.
>
> `F4`, `\`: Incremental process filtering: type in part of a process command line and only processes whose names match will be shown. To cancel filtering, enter the Filter option again and press Esc.

Comment: just pressing / is enough, F3 is an alternate button for it.

Comment: That is to say, `// firefox.exe.dll.so`

Comment: Perhaps worth adding that backslash `\\` filters as opposed to searches, so you are presented with only matches, rather than your process(es) just highlighted amongst the rest.

Comment: but what if i need higlight 2 and more  like: `top | grep 'first\|second\|another'`

Comment: How about if I want to see the total of the processes I've filtered by?

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

htop --filter "process_name"